# MySQLi prepared statement silently failing second execution

Tags: php, mysqli

I am attempting to make a simple system where, once you view  forum thread it updates an existing array entry with the current UNIX time in the DB table that holds the user's account information. The column is set to accept MEDIUMTEXT and is set as NOT NULL.

However, while the first prepared statement works as intended and I receive the correct value, and the json_table is correctly re-encoded, the second query does not update the column data. No errors (no matter what error level I set mysqli to). Neither of the parameters I am binding are NULL and are correct.

I am stumped as to why this is happening. MySQLi magic that I haven't learned? Restrictions somewhere?

```
    $DB = GetDatabaseConnection();
    $Statement = $DB->prepare("SELECT `forum_newpost_icondata` FROM `user_accounts` WHERE `id` = ?");
    print(mysqli_error($DB));
    $Statement->bind_param("i", $UserLoggedIn['id']);
    $Statement->bind_result($JSONTable);
    $Statement->execute();

    $PostData = json_decode($JSONTable);
    $PostData[$ThreadID] = time();
    $PostData = (string)json_encode($PostData);

    $Statement->free_result();
    $Statement->close();

    $Reinsertion = $DB->prepare("UPDATE `user_accounts` SET `forum_newpost_icondata` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
    print(mysqli_error($DB));
    $Reinsertion->bind_param("si", $PostData, $UserLoggedIn['id']);
    $Reinsertion->execute();
    print(mysqli_error($DB)); // Checking after execute is still blank
    $DB->close();
```

Comment: You're not checking for mysql errors after you executed a statement

Comment: I just did so. Blank. Nothing.

Comment: Use `print_r($DB->errorInfo());` after the second `execute` to see if it gives you any errors.

Comment: Why do you think there is an error then?

Comment: @ssergei Undefined method. Looks like PDO.

Comment: @zerkms Because both the values are I am binding in the second statement are valid and not null. However, the database is still showing an empty string for the column I want to update.

Comment: Storing JSON data in a database and then trying to manipulate it is a really bad idea. You should modify your database design such that the data held in your JSON column is held in its own columns. Then most of this malarkey could be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interested in the root cause of this rather than creating a bunch of columns for this. The database _should_ not have problems with simply storing a string, am I wrong?

Comment: Could possibly be an escaping issue? too many slashes not enough love?

Comment: For your error checking try this: `if(!($Reinsertion->execute())){   echo "Error:(" . $Reinsertion->errno . ") " . $Reinsertion->error;}` and see if that gives you something to work with.